# Crystal Report Detail Section Height Not Decreasing

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in my winform project using c# which is working perfectly, except the **Height of Detail section**. I want to decrease the height of detail section but Visual Studio 2012 designer is not allowing to do so. I want to fix height of this section equal to three rows only. There is an attribute in properties section namely **Minimum Height having value 1229 and is disable**. [See this screenshot describing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGGbR.png) Is there any way to decrease this preset 1229 value? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Probably, there is an object in the way. Try to increase the section height to visualize if there is a line in the way. You may try to right click it and select the "fit" option too. Furthermore, you may try do create a new detail section and move the content to new one and then delete the old one.

Comment: @heringer Thanks for your suggestion. I did same created new detailed section moved all data to new section then deleted old detail section. All is working perfectly now.